# Prove that if $(f_n)_{n \geq 1} \to f$ uniformly then $f_n \to f \in B(X)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence

> Let $B(X)$ be the set of bounded functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{C}$ where $X$ is any metric space. Let $(f_n)_{n \geq 1} $ be a sequence in $B(X)$.
>   Show that if $f_n \to f$ uniformly where $f:X\to \mathbb{C}$ is bounded then $f_n \to f$ in $B(X,d_{\infty})$.

Now, since $f_n \to f$ uniformly, given $\epsilon >0$ there exist $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ if $n\geq n_0$ for any $x\in X$. I wasn't sure, I could automatically imply that $sup_{x\in X}|f_n(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon$ since this is not true in general. However when reading my textbook, the author states that since $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon, \forall x$ then $sup_{x\in X}|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon$. I assume he is using in such a way that $f_n$ is bounded. Is that step trivial?

Comment: Consider the set $\{\vert f_n(x) - f(x) \vert  \, \vert x \in X\}$. It has an upper bound given by $\varepsilon$. Hence the supremum exists and is smaller than $\varepsilon$. This does only use the uniform convergence of $(f_n)_n$, no boundedness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subtlety in the order of the quantifiers. Uniformity garuntees that the bound
$$
|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon 
$$
holds for all $x$ and all $n>n_0$ for *the same* $\varepsilon$. So, the $\sup |f_n(x)-f(x)| $ can't be greater than $\varepsilon$ if for each $x$ and $n>n_0$ the quantity $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ isn't greater than $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

There exists $n_0$ such that

$$|f_{n_0}(x)-f(x)|< 1, x \in X.$$

We have $|f_{n_0}(x)|< M$ on $X$ for some $M>0.$ It follows that

$$|f(x)|\le |f(x)-f_{n_0}(x)| + |f_{n_0}(x)| < 1 + M$$

for all $x\in X.$